# How can I properly tidy a Date column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, I have a dataframe with a Date column. The current values are of object type and are in the form: 'Jun 2021'. I would like to convert this to: '2021-06' and for all the other hundreds of Date values.

I keep getting errors with different functions and solutions posted from other stack threads, but I cant figure this out.

Comment: [`pd.to_datetime('Jun 2021', format='%b %Y')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) You can directly use `to_datetime` on your column. [`datetime` format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column is of string datatype

```
from datetime import datetime

x= row_length
date_object=[]
for i in range(X):
    date_object[i] = datetime.strptime(date_string[i], "%d %B")
```

in the end append this date object list as a column and remove the original column( if that's how you want to have your data).
Example code:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = ["15 July","19 May","14 August","16 December"]

print("date_string =", date_string)
print("type of date_string =", type(date_string))
for i in range(len(date_string)):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string[i], "%d %B")
    print("date_object =", date_object)
```

You get output something like this:

- date_object = 1900-07-15 00:00:00
- date_object = 1900-05-19 00:00:00
- date_object = 1900-08-14 00:00:00
- date_object = 1900-12-16 00:00:00